# Is there any way to get time difference between two time that cross midnight?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get difference between two time. The difference is ok when the time is within same day. But get wrong result when time cross midnight.

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '08:00',DATEADD(minute,-60, '17:00'))
```

give me the result 480 which is correct. but

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '20:00',DATEADD(minute,-60, '05:00'))
```

Give me the result -960 which is wrong. How can i handle it? I don't want to use DateTime datatype.

Comment: `I don't want to use DateTime datatype` ... but this is precisely what you should be using.  As you have already seen, time alone can't keep track of which day it is.

Comment: is there anyone to answer my question?

Comment: Is that mean i have to use DateTime Data Type instead of Time?

Comment: This is what I would probably do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one trick. No need to use `case`. Will work in both cases

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(minute, '08:00',DATEADD(minute,-60, '17:00')) + 1440) % 1440
SELECT (DATEDIFF(minute, '20:00',DATEADD(minute,-60, '05:00')) + 1440) % 1440
```

Output is 480 in both cases

1440 - amount of minutes in one day. Adding 1440 to cases when datediff returns negative value will return correct value. While for second case result will be some value more than 1 day. In that case we need to remove extra value which 1440. For that `% 1440` is needed

Comment: can you please tell me the logic? @uzi

Comment: Edited answer, @SyedIslam

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement and in these circumstances, you need to add a day and get result like,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '20:00',DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(minute,-60, '05:00')))
```

Comment: that would be a great solution without using DateTime. Thanks a lot. 
 @sanatsathyan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, '20:00',getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query...make necessary changes accordingly.

CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,DateOutColumn,103) > CONVERT(DATE,DateInColumn,103)
THEN ((ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME,TimeInColumn,108),'23:59:00.0000000')))+1+(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME,TimeOutColumn,108),'00:00:00.0000000'))))/60
ELSE
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME,TimeInColumn,108),CONVERT(TIME,TimeOutColumn,108)))/60